# How to set up a generic webhook trigger in Tekton

Tags: openshift, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I want to set up a webhook trigger in tekton. [In the documentation](https://github.com/tektoncd/triggers), I can find Github, Gitlab and bitbucket triggers available. But I want a generic webhook that processes HTTP POST and reads the JSON body.

For example: I am doing the following with Jenkins' generic webhook trigger.

Prometheus Alertmanager sends a HTTP POST to Jenkins' Generic webhook and Jenkins processes the JSON body and kicks off the build.

I want to the same with Tekton. Alertmanager sends a HTTP POST to the Tekton webhook and it would process the JSON body and kick off the build.

Is this doable with Tekton's webhook trigger? Is this not available yet in tekton or am i missing something form the [documentation](https://github.com/tektoncd/triggers)?

If someone has already done this, can you point me in the right direction? I am using openshift 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should work fine.

You create an [EventListener](https://github.com/tektoncd/triggers/blob/master/examples/eventlisteners/eventlistener.yaml) - this spins up a `Deployment` and a `Service` that you somehow has to expose, e.g. using a `Route` on OpenShift or `Ingress` in Kubernetes - and that is the url that your Prometheus Alertmanager should send it's POST request to.

Also create a [TriggerBinding](https://github.com/tektoncd/triggers/blob/master/examples/triggerbindings/triggerbinding.yaml) where you can declare *jsonPaths* to retrieve data from your JSON-payload into parameters.

And finally you need a [TriggerTemplate](https://github.com/tektoncd/triggers/blob/master/examples/triggertemplates/triggertemplate.yaml) to declare what Tekton resource your trigger should create, for each event, typically a [PipelineRun](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/blob/master/docs/pipelineruns.md) and you should declare how you should map the params from your TriggerBinding to the params in your PipelineRun.

Comment: thank you! I just figured it out Yesterday. I’m still putting it together. Now, I know that I’m doing it right. Thanks very much for your explanation.